# how to minimize the absolute difference?

Tags: algorithm, logic

> we are given a number n. we have to find two (i.e-sum1,sum2), such that sum1+sum2=sum of digits[1 to n] and the absolute difference of sum1 and sum2 is minimized.

```
eg:-let n=3

sum1=1+2
sum2=3
abs(3-3)=0 (minimum possible value that we can get)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of writing `sum1=1+2`? Is it related to the question somehow? Also can `sum1` and `sum2` be negative?

Comment: You want sum of all digits from `1` to `n` or sum of all numbers from `1` to `n`?

Comment: the purpose is two distribute the total sum of n digits in two parts such (assume we have two variables sum1  and sum2 and sum1+sum2==n(n+1) / 2) but absolute(sum1-sum2) must be minimum

Answer (score 0):

My function findSum1Sum2(n) receive an integer positive number "n" (parameter) and sum all number n digits. Then find sum1 and sum2 with two conditions:

- sum1 + sum2 = sum of all digits of number n.
- |sum1 - sum2| is minimized.

I assume sum1 and sum2 can have the same value.

```js
function findSum1Sum2(n) {
  if(Number.isInteger(n) && n >= 0) {
    let sumNumberDigits = 0;
    let sum1, sum2;

    for(let d of n.toString()) {
      sumNumberDigits += parseInt(d);
    }

    if(sumNumberDigits % 2 == 0) {
      sum1 = sum2 = sumNumberDigits / 2;
    } else {
      sum1 = Math.floor(sumNumberDigits / 2);
      sum2 = sum1 + 1;
    }

    console.log(`sum1 is ${sum1} and sum2 is ${sum2}. sum1 + sum2 is ${sum1 + sum2}. |sum1 - sum2| is ${Math. abs( sum1 - sum2)}.`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${n} is not an integer positive number.`);
  }
  
}

findSum1Sum2(3); //result -> sum1: 1 and sum2: 2.
findSum1Sum2(111); //result -> sum1: 1 and sum2: 2.
findSum1Sum2(4); //result -> sum1: 2 and sum2: 2.
findSum1Sum2(4388); //result -> sum1: 2 and sum2: 2.
```